# Why is imperialism not spelled empirialism?

Tags: etymology, orthography

If the goal of imperialism is to create an empire, why is the word not spelled "empirialism"?

Comment: Does this question boil down to: "why are *imperial* and *empire* spelled differently, despite having a common Latin root"?

Comment: Yes, exactly, looking this up, I often find the word "empiricism" which has a fully different meaning and thus I suspect that in order to avoid confusion with this word, the "imper-" root was preferred.

Comment: The Latin root of *imperial* and *empire* is *imperator*, which is why *im-* is preferred for *imperial*. Quite why it is not preferred for *empire* is a different question -- which you could ask here.

Comment: @CongXu Or, "How did the transformation from *imperare* to *empire* happen?"

Comment: I'd wanted to answer *empire* was borrowed from French (where *imperium* > *empire* via the usual sound changes from Latin to French), whilst *imperial* was borrowed directly from the Latin (i.e., from *imperialis*). A look at the OED, however, shows that *imperial* is also a borrowing from French, and indeed, the first cited use, from 1390, gives the spelling *emperiall*. I can only guess that the Old French original (sometimes itself spelled with *i*) was itself a learned borrowing from Classical Latin, or that the English loan was eventually re-identified as a borrowing directly from Latin.

Comment: Latin terms came into European languages at several times, repeatedly, and later borrowings missed the previous sound changes. Rather like English _skirt_, borrowed from Old Norse, which is the same word as native English _shirt_, which had previously gone through a sound change. So we have two words for apparel instead of one, and efficiently use them for different pieces.

Answer (score 5):

*[Imperialism](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=imperialism&allowed_in_frame=0)* is first recorded in English in 1826, from *imperial + ism*.

The Online Etymology Dictionary says of *[imperial](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=imperial&allowed_in_frame=0)*:

> late 14c., "having a commanding quality," from Old French *imperial* (12c.), from Latin *imperialis* "of the empire or emperor," from *imperium* (see *empire*). Meaning "pertaining to an empire" (especially the Roman) is from late 14c.

And for *[empire](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=empire&allowed_in_frame=0)*:

> early 14c., from Old French *empire* "rule, authority, kingdom, imperial rule," from Latin *imperium* "rule, command," from *imperare* "to command," from *im*- "in" (see *in*- (2)) + *parare* "to order, prepare" (see *pare*).

So both English words have roots in the Latin *imperium* (at one stage or another) and come to English via Old French where they spelled one with an E and one with an I.

Answer (score -1):

Empire is essentially a French mutation of the Latin Imperium, which stems from the original Latin word Imperare which means "to command".

http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=empire&allowed_in_frame=0